# Get OS Info in Consistent Format

Tags: language-agnostic, operating-system

For context, I currently use OS X, but I'm also interested to hear how this problem might be solved in Linux.

In many cases, I want to query a piece of info such as:

- ID of a process listening on a particular port.
- Amount of memory being used a particular process.
- Any other piece of info relating to system resources etc.

I can achieve this relatively easily using shell commands (ps, lsof, etc).

My problem is that these commands invariably return a wall of formatted text, usually resembling a table. That's fine for quick terminal commands.

However, when I use these commands in application development, I have to slice and dice the results to get the exact piece of info I'm after. In some cases, the results are formatted in such a way that makes them difficult to parse.

Is there a way to query OS info that returns results in a consistent and easy-to-parse format? For example, I'd be happy with anything similar to CSV, JSON, XML etc.

I'm hoping the answer won't be, "That's just the way it is".

Thanks

Comment: Are you only interested in OSX and Linux? There are 2 or 3 other operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, information related to a process can be read from and certain parameters can be written into the proc file system.You would still have to parse the results of

> /proc/(pid)/(parameter)

but I guess it's better than executing shell commands from your program.

> man proc

for more details.